# How to stop Android Studio from trying to install Android SDK updates?

Tags: android-studio

I have linked my Android Studio project's Android SDK Directory to our software team's standard Android SDK directory (I can't change it, so please save the effort of typing "I can't understand why you don't simply use the normal path from Android Studio :-) ).

I have disabled automatic updates in Android Studio (see screenshot).  Then closed and re-opened the project.

Yet, every time I try to build, it tries to install an update to Android SDK and fails.

How can I stop Android Studio from trying to install unwanted updates?
[image]

Comment: did you try to turn it of from android studio sdk manager?

Comment: I did "Help -> Check for Updates -> Configure automatic updates" in Android Studio

Comment: what are you thinking about `disable sdk diff patching` maybe it will help you?

Comment: and also at settings you can check `Updates` item here you can also turn off automatic updates

Comment: when you enter to AS settings ->appearance&behaviour->system settings -> updates

Comment: and also `disable sdk diff patching` is available from sdk manager, at the bottom of this page

Comment: OK I found the Updates in System Settings...they are the same as in the screenshot above, i.e. the automatic updates box is not checked.

Comment: and what about diff patching?

Comment: sdk manager is placed on main toolbar it looks like square with blue arrow

Comment: OK I now checked the check box "Disable sdk diff patching" in the sdk manager...sadly, it makes no difference.  Android Studio is still trying to install the 28.0.3 update.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a bug because it had already downloaded this update, and isn't ignoring it properly.